# Can't change log detail levels permanently with a Jython script (WAS 7)

Tags: websphere, jython, websphere-7

I'm trying to change WebSphere's Log Detail Levels with a Jython script:

```
..
AdminTask.setTraceSpecification('[-serverName server1 -nodeName qnode -traceSpecification com.ibm.*=all=enabled]')
AdminConfig.save()
..
```

After successfully running the script I'm checking "Logging and Tracing > {server_name} > Diagnostic trace service > Change log detail levels. The Runtime tab reflects the setting (the traceSpecification) I've entered in my script, but the Configuration tab remains unchanged, so, my setting doesn't get saved to configuration. I've tried restarting my server, so I'm sure about that's the case.

According to setTraceSpecification's documentation, this "command also saves the trace specification in configuration." Well, not in my case:) Do you have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I've found out, setTraceSpecification() also has a persist parameter which has to be set if you want to change your setting permanently to WAS configuration:

```
..
AdminTask.setTraceSpecification('[-serverName myserver -nodeName mynode -persist true -traceSpecification com.ibm.*=all=enabled]')
AdminConfig.save()
..
```

Unfortunately, [WAS 7 InfoCenter](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/info/aes/ae/rxml_7libserver.html) doesn't have a single word about this option, while WebSphere CloudBurst Appliance InfoCenter has an [example](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wscloudb/v1r1m1/topic/com.ibm.websphere.cloudburst.doc/pc/pcr_configtrace_sample.html) which includes it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to also save the configuration in your script:

```
if (AdminConfig.hasChanges()):
    AdminConfig.save()
```

Comment: Yes, calling save() is also in my script, just forgot to mention it. I've edited my answer. Thanks anyway!