# Control logging level by WebSphere admin console

Tags: logging, websphere, java.util.logging

I have a web application in which I am using java.util.logging. In my logging.properties files default level is info. 
I have loggers in my application for all levels of logging (info, debug, fatal etc).
This web application will be deployed on WebSphere 8.

What if I want to change logging level, lets say from info to error, of application through WAS admin console at runtime? How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 6):

In addition to [Magic Wand](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26116721/3701228) answer:

- Changes on the Configuration tab are valid *after* server restart
- Changes on the Runtime tab *are valid only till server restart* unless you checked `Save runtime changes to configuration as well`
- You can either type your trace string in the text area, or select it using the `Components` tree (your packages may not be visible, if classes were not loaded yet)
- All messages with levels `fine, finer, finest` will go to the `trace.log` not to the `SystemOut.log`.

Answer (score 5):

Log into WAS Admin console and click on Troubleshooting->Logs and trace->your server->Diagnostic trace service->Change log level details.

There you can add your own log levels, e.g.

```
com.example.test.*=all
```

You can change it permanently, or you can change log levels dynamically on runtime (tab "Runtime"). Log levels are separated with ':'.

Comment: I have tried this option. Problem is it controls the log of WAS server. I want to control log of my application which is getting generated in myapp.log file.

Comment: Is there any way to do this from a configuration file or something like that? I can't access the admin console so my only option is changing it from the file system.

Comment: There is an option to do it via a jython script, which basically boils down to run a shell script on a WAS server directly. More details about log level change via a jython script can be found on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12383413/cant-change-log-detail-levels-permanently-with-a-jython-script-was-7. Moreover, you can run wsadmin script from your computer on a remote WAS instance, details can be found here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_7.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/txml_j2se.html